# Remove excess array braces due to multiple nested map function

Tags: javascript

I created multiple nested map function of an object array and I ended up in the kind of output.

```
let tags =  product.map(item => item.outSourceItem.map(outsourceitem => outsourceitem.tags));
```

```js
 tags = [
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 11,
                "name": "eleven"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 12,
                "name": "twelve"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 13,
                "name": "thirteen"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 11,
                "name": "eleven"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

I just want it to be like this.

```js
[
    {
        "_id": 11,
        "name": "eleven"
    },
    {
        "_id": 12,
        "name": "twelve"
    },
    {
        "_id": 13,
        "name": "thirteen"
    },
    {
        "_id": 11,
        "name": "eleven"
    }
]
```

any one liner function for this? I use `.flat()` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `.map`. Also, "but it doesn't work" is not a useful description of a problem. What happens if you do? How does it differ from what you want?

Comment: You are only missing the depth in the `flat()` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) with `depth` of `infinity`:

```js
const tags = [
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 11,
                "name": "eleven"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 12,
                "name": "twelve"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 13,
                "name": "thirteen"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "_id": 11,
                "name": "eleven"
            }
        ]
    ]
];

const result = tags.flat(Infinity);

console.log(result);
```